# Поиск по шаблону с дефисом

Tags: bash, grep, sed, awk

Как средствами grep/sed/awk из списка строк вычленить строки, которые удовлетворяют только шаблону вида `[a-z]-[a-z]/*`?

В части строки до слеша обязательно должен быть дефис.

Comment: а какие перед вами встали проблемы? `grep '[a-z]-[a-z]/*'` работает вполне корректно.

Comment: Не работает. Он выводит и те строки, в которых нет дефиса до слэша.

Comment: не подтверждаю: `echo -e 'xx\nx-x' | grep '[a-z]-[a-z]/*'` возвращает одну строку `x-x`, как и ожидается. какая реализация и версия *grep* вами используется? приведите и пример строк, дополнив ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: А по идее он не должен в этом случае ничего выводить, т.к. мне нужны только строки с дефисом в первой части (до слэша), а не во второй (после слэша). Вот в чём тонкость.

Comment: т.е., в начале строки должно быть любое (в том числе и нулевое) количество символов из диапазона `a-z` **и** один (или больше) символ `-`. я правильно понял условие?

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Хватит обычного grep, только нужно исправить само регулярное выражение:

```
$ cat file | grep "^[a-z]*-[a-z]*/.*"
```

Comment: Алилуйя, это оно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

попытаюсь угадать. возможно, требуется привязка к началу строки.

вот так, действительно, строка пройдёт фильтр:

```
$ echo -e 'xx/x-x' | grep '[a-z]-[a-z]/*'
xx/x-x
$
```

а так — нет:

```
$ echo -e 'xx/x-x' | grep '^[a-z]-[a-z]/*'
$
```

**дополнение**

если требуется, чтобы фильтр проходили все строки, в начале которых должно быть любое (в том числе и нулевое) количество символов из диапазона `a-z` и один (или больше) символ `-`, то можно использовать такое регулярное выражение:

```
$ echo -e 'xxx-\nxx-x\n--xxx\nxxx' | grep '^[a-z-]*-[a-z-]*'
xxx-
xx-x
--xxx
```

если же к набору символов более «мягкие» требования — среди них всего лишь не должно быть символа `/` — то можно так:

```
$ echo -e 'xZx-/z\nxx-!\n--.xx\nxxx\nxxx/' | grep '^[^/]*-[^/]*'
xZx-/z
xx-!
--.xx
```

Comment: У вас неверное регулярное выражение, оно пропустит 'a-z/aaa', но не пропустит 'aa-z/aaa' или '-z/aaa', то есть у вас дефис обязательно должен быть вторым символом.

Comment: @VadimShender, совершенно верно, но такое условие изложено в вопросе.